# Connecting Phones together by making a mobile server

Tags: android

I want to make server a phone then connect other phones to the Server phone and for example send a message with a phone to the server phone and show the message on all phones

Like Minecraft Lan in mobile (A mobile entering its wold then other mobiles can join it's world)

Some ideas? Please?

Comment: Unclear what you want to know.

Comment: What you want is only possible if the server phone uses wifi. With a mobile connection the provider mostly blocks incoming connections.

Comment: I want to communicate between several phones in Android and transfer some information from one phone to all phones

Comment: Yes, we know. But why dont you comment on my comment?

Comment: I read your comment. Is this possible? If yes, please help me

Comment: I said that it was only possible if the server phone uses wifi. Conclusion: it's possible.

Comment: I know , but how?

Comment: In the usual way with a server and clients.